# Sprite layers are disappearing in AS3 drawing code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm building a custom painting application, and I'm running into a problem where the layers I'm adding to the canvas are disappearing after 24 layers get added.

Here is my code for the drawing tools:

```
    //=====================================================================================================================================
    // DRAWING FUNCTIONS
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected function onMouseDown_canvas( evt:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        var p:Point = new Point( _realView.mouseX, _realView.mouseY );

        _log.log( "CanvasViewController :: onMouseDown_canvas() - mouse:" + p );

        _realView.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,   onMouseUp_canvas );
        _realView.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,  onMouseOut_canvas );
        _realView.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove_canvas );

        _currentLayer = new Sprite();
        _currentLayer.mouseEnabled = false;
        _realView.mcContainer.addChild( _currentLayer );

        _$clearFirstBrushStroke = false;

        switch( _$tool )
        {
            case ToolType.ERASER:
            case ToolType.BRUSH:
            case ToolType.PENCIL:
                _currentLayer.graphics.beginFill(
                    ( _$tool == ToolType.ERASER ? 0xffffff : _$color ),
                    ( _$tool == ToolType.BRUSH  ? .4 : 1 )
                );
                _currentLayer.graphics.drawCircle( p.x, p.y, _$toolSize/2 )
                _currentLayer.graphics.endFill();
                _firstPoint = p;
                _$clearFirstBrushStroke = true;
                if( _$tool == ToolType.BRUSH )
                    _currentLayer.filters = [ new BlurFilter( 3, 3, 2 ) ];
                break;
            case ToolType.BRUSH2:
                drawGlitter( _currentLayer.graphics, p );
                break;
        }
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected function onMouseUp_canvas( evt:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        var p:Point = new Point( _realView.mouseX, _realView.mouseY );
        _log.log( "CanvasViewController :: onMouseUp_canvas() - mouse:" + p );
        endDrawing();
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected function onMouseMove_canvas( evt:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        var p:Point = new Point( _realView.mouseX, _realView.mouseY );

        switch( _$tool )
        {
            case ToolType.ERASER:
            case ToolType.BRUSH:
            case ToolType.PENCIL:
                if( _$clearFirstBrushStroke )
                {
                    _$clearFirstBrushStroke = false;
                    _currentLayer.graphics.clear();
                    _currentLayer.graphics.lineStyle( 
                        _$toolSize, 
                        ( _$tool == ToolType.ERASER ? 0xffffff : _$color ),
                        ( _$tool == ToolType.BRUSH  ? .4 : 1 ),
                        true,
                        LineScaleMode.NORMAL,
                        CapsStyle.ROUND,
                        JointStyle.ROUND
                    );
                    _currentLayer.graphics.moveTo( _firstPoint.x, _firstPoint.y );
                }
                _currentLayer.graphics.lineTo( p.x, p.y );
                break;
            case ToolType.BRUSH2:
                drawGlitter( _currentLayer.graphics, p );
                break;
        }
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected function onMouseOut_canvas( evt:MouseEvent ):void
    {
        var p:Point = new Point( _realView.mouseX, _realView.mouseY );
        _log.log( "CanvasViewController :: onMouseOut_canvas() - mouse:" + p );
        endDrawing();
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected function endDrawing():void
    {
        var p:Point = new Point( _realView.mouseX, _realView.mouseY );
        _log.log( "CanvasViewController :: endDrawing() - mouse:" + p );

        _realView.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,   onMouseUp_canvas );
        _realView.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,  onMouseOut_canvas );
        _realView.removeEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove_canvas );

        var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData( _realView.width, _realView.height, true, 0x00000000 );
        bmd.draw( _currentLayer );
        var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap( bmd, "auto", true );

        _realView.mcContainer.removeChild( _currentLayer );
        _realView.mcContainer.addChild( bmp );

        _currentLayer = null;

        _log.log( "  numChildren:" + _realView.mcContainer.numChildren );
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected function drawGlitter( g:Graphics, c:Point, $glitterSize:Number = 2, $density:Number = .5 ):void
    {
        var $startAngle:Number = NewMath.Random( 0, Math.PI*2 );
        var $stepAngle:Number = $startAngle / ( $density * _$toolSize );

        for( var $i:int = 0; $i < ( $density * _$toolSize ); $i++ )
        {
            var $a:Number = $startAngle + ( $i * $stepAngle );
            var $r:Number = NewMath.Random( 0, _$toolSize / 2 );
            var p:Point = new Point( c.x + Math.cos( $a ) * $r, c.y + Math.sin( $a ) * $r );
            g.beginFill( _$color, 1 );
            g.drawCircle( p.x, p.y, $glitterSize / 2 );
            g.endFill();
        }
    }
```

numChildren continues to grow, but once it hits 24 layers in that container, the first layer gets deleted or goes invisible or something. at 25 layers, the second layer disappears, etc.

See this in action here: http://dev.option5.net/CAUS/CAUS14002/index.html

Could it be a masking issue? Can only so many layers be masked : _realView.mcContainer (where new layers are added) is masked by _realView.mcMask?

Comment: I have encountered a similar problen when I've got me a decent ton of stacking `Bitmap` objects and got white where it shouldn't have been. Yes, it's likely an issue of how Flash deals with alpha channel.

Comment: I've discovered it was, indeed, the masking issue. If I unmasked the layer where I was adding the newly created Bitmaps, I can put as many as I want (tested up to 500 layers).

To correct my program, I changed the name of `mcContainer` (which is masked) to `mcDrawingLayer`. I still add my `_currentLayer` to the display list of `mcDrawingLayer`. In the `endDrawing()` function, I remove `_currentLayer` from `mcDrawingLayer`, turn it into a bitmap, and then add that to a new `mcCanvasLayers` movieclip which isn't masked. All works perfectly now.